# Why is this circuit not working?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, proteus, 555

[image]

I was making this **automatic street light** project with a slight change i.e replacing LDR with vibration sensor on proteus.

While using LDR it worked well as it changed color depending upon light (red for no light and yellow for light.) I want to use vibration ensor instead.

What should I do here?

Comment: You could try not shorting the output of the sensor to your power supply.

Comment: Tips for future posts: (1) Turn off the grid before taking a screengrab. This will make text easier to read. (2) Use GND symbols right at the component where possible. It declutters the schematic and makes it instantly clear what is grounded.

Answer (score 1):

Your LDR when exposed to light changes its resistance which in combination with the potentiometer make a voltage-divider. This changes the voltage on the TR (trigger) pin of the NE555 and causes it to change its output.

The vibration sensor does not work this way, In your schematic you have shorted the output of the sensor to 12V line on BAT1. In your circuit remove the connection of RV1 to 12V and instead connect it to the output of the sensor.